# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Tags: selenium

I was running one class in Selenium and suddenly receiving below error.

## Error Details:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-CT7IBV5D', ip: '9.236.152.55', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:276)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getText(RemoteWebElement.java:160)
    at **com.qa.PhpTravels.Pages.PhpTravelsSearchHotelPage.SearchHotelByLocation(PhpTravelsSearchHotelPage.java:67)
    at com.qa.PhpTravels.TestCases.PhpTravelsSearchHotelPageTest.SearchHotelByLocationTest(PhpTravelsSearchHotelPageTest.java:58)**

I verified my code in SearchHotelByLocation and couldn't understand why it is failing.

```
List<WebElement> SearchLocationList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='select2-results']/li/ul/li/div/span"));
        int NumberOfSearchLocation=SearchLocationList.size();
        System.out.println("Total Length of SearchLocation:"+NumberOfSearchLocation);
        if(NumberOfSearchLocation==0)
            {
                System.out.println("Please search some different location");
            }
        else
            {
                for(int i=0;i<NumberOfSearchLocation;i++)
                {
                    **System.out.println("Value in 1 index:"+SearchLocationList.get(i).getText());**
                    if(SearchLocationList.get(i).getText().contains(location))
                        {
                            SearchLocationList.get(i).click();
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Which chrome driver you are using?

Comment: @Ankur: I am using Geckodriver... but there are several calls which are working fine. This part of code is a part of one of the class in my PageObjectModel TDD framwork. Whenever the code is reaching the section highlighted by ** it is throwing error.

Comment: @Arka Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: Hi Debanjan.. this issue seems to be intermittent and not seeing the issue always.